# issue with move uploaded file in php

Tags: php, image

I am making an image compressor tool to compress image size

for that, I have made code which is given below

```
<?php
$name  = '';
$type  = '';
$size  = '';
$error = '';
function compress_image($source_url, $destination_url, $quality)
{
    $info = getimagesize($source_url);
    if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') {
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_url);
        imagejpeg($image, $destination_url, $quality);
    } elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') {
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($source_url);
        imagegif($image, $destination_url, $quality);
    } elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') {
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($source_url);
        imagepng($image, $destination_url, 5);
    }
    return $destination_url;
}
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
    $error = $_FILES["file"]["error"];
} else if (($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")) {
    $url       = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $temp_file = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    $filename  = compress_image($temp_file, $url, 80);
    rename($filename, 'https://example.com/wp-content/themes/twentytwenty/templates/images/' . $filename);
    $location = "https://example.com/wp-content/themes/twentytwenty/templates/images/" . $url;
    /*$image_size = getimagesize($location);*/
    echo 'https://example.com/wp-content/themes/twentytwenty/templates/images/' . $filename; die();
} else {
    $error = "Uploaded image should be jpg or gif or png";
}
```

but my issue with a file can not be moved in image folder it is creating in `https://example.com/wp-content/themes/twentytwenty/templates/` only

I don't know why it is a problem

can anybody help me with this

Comment: why are you renaming the file using https urls? They should be absolute/relative urls.. (when working server-side like this)

Comment: You can't rename a file to a URL. Renaming is for moving local files on the server.

Comment: @Barmar then what can I do for server side

Comment: @treyBake then how can I move my file in folder

Comment: Use the local pathname that you want to move to, not a URL.

Comment: @Barmar what do you mean by that

Comment: @Barmar it still can not move without any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a local pathname in `rename()`, not a URL. You can use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to get the root of your web site.

```
rename($filename, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/themes/twentytwenty/templates/images/' . $filename);
```